# Free memory ARC removing array of views elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a 2D array which represents a grid (every element in the array is an array which elements are cells).

I have also an array "ARRAY_X" containing grids, that is, an array containing this 2D arrays (grids). I am using ARC and I am removing elements from "ARRAY_X" (remove the first one with `removeObjectAtIndex:0`) and adding new ones (at the end with `addObject:...`).

The problem is than seeing the memory usage in xCode, every time I remove en element from "ARRAY_X" and added a new one, the memory is increased (due to the new element, but another element has been removed...)

I've tried removing all the elements in the 2D array arrays, that is:

```
for (int row=0; row<[[ARRAY_X objectAtIndex:0] count]; row++) {
        [[[ARRAY_X objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:row] removeAllObjects];
    }
    [[arrGrids objectAtIndex:0] removeAllObjects];
    [ARRAY_X removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

But the memory continues increasing. How can I release this memory?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your allocator playing tricks on you.
You should run "leaks" to know whether you really have leaks or not, and "heap" to know what allocations your software really is doing.

**EDIT**

And btw, I think that `[ARRAY_X removeObjectAtIndex:0]` will do what you do with your loops for you, because it will send `-release` to that object which will in turn delete the collections within, unless someone else has a reference on it obviously (but then I would argue that you probably didn't want to destroy the contents under his feet anyway).